# How to change layout based on classes?

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website here i need add a functionality i.e when i hover on a particular division all the other elements will be hidden and background color of body changes, this would be done for three cases. Any example would be very appreciable. Thanks in advance .

Posted reference   https://longstoryshortdesign.co.uk/projects

Comment: Please provide the code you have done so far.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to make an attempt so that we can help you fix your code.

Comment: I know but i need help here is what stackoverflow is for i think @Soviut

Comment: StackOverflow is for helping you solve problems with your code. We are not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
 $('your-class-name').hover(
   function() {
   // your mouse hover event
    $(this).removeClass("your-class-name");
   },
  function() {
  // your mouse out event
   }
 );
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i need to remove older class too on hover of another function

Comment: yes then you like this, please check my code again @AnmolSandal

Comment: please mark tick if my answer is helpful to you. @AnmolSandal

Comment: I am also jquery expert and you can share on my skype: ajay.malhotra70

Comment: That would be helpful

Comment: That is much helpful, i have sent a request on skype

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".project").mouseover(function() {
$(".project").css("opacity","0.5");
  $(this).css("opacity","1");
   });
$(".project").mouseout(function() {
$(".project").css("opacity","1")
});  
  });
```

```css
div{border:1px solid #b8b8b8;
height:30px;margin-bottom:10px;background:#b8b8b8;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="project project-1 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-2 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-3 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-4 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-5 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-6 ">This is a division</div>
<div class="project project-7 ">This is a division</div>
```

In this we have two events mouseover() and mouseout()
Mouseover() will change the opacity to 0.5 for background(which can be any CSS property you like)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here a CSS solution (without Jquery). Use a class on the body

```
a:hover {
   background: blue;
}
body.case1 a:hover {
   background: green;
}
body.case2 a:hover {
   background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just given a try with the CSS. Please check

CSS

```
.test_div {
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ccc;
}
.test:hover .test_div {
    background:#ccc;
    opacity:.5;
}
.test .test_div:hover {
    background:#0ff;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML Structure

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
    <div class="test_div">This is test div</div>
</div>
```

Thanks